# Material UI - center an element vertically inside FlexBox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

In my react app I created a card with min width and height and it contains only a header. I would like to add a flexbox which would take the whole left space with `justify-content="center"` and `align-items="center"` so when I add a circular progress element it will be in the middle of the card. Unforunately whatever I do the flexbox's height equals the loading spinner height and it does not take the whole space. How to fix it? 
My Component:

```
   function AccountSettings({isLoading, id, username, isDisable}) {
        const classes = useStyles();

        return (
            <Card
                className={classes.accountSettings}
            >
                <CardHeader
                    title="Something"
                />
                <Divider/>
                    <Box
                        display="flex"
                        alignItems="center"
                        justifyContent="center"
                        height={"100%"}
                        width={"100%"}
                    >
                        <CircularProgress/>
                    </Box>
            </Card>
        );
    }
```

My style:

```
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/styles";

export default makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        maxWidth: "1000px"
    },
    pageTitle: {
        padding: "5px"
    },
    accountSettings: {
        minWidth: "312px",
        minHeight: "273px",
    }
}));
```

And here my main view:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
    <AccountSettings/>
</div>
```

This image shows my issue
[image: issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is one solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-euclid-2kzf9)

Add the following to the styles:

```
accountSettings: {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column'
},
box: {
  flexGrow: 1
}
```

And add the class to the `Box` element:

```
<Box
  className={classes.box}
```